# AWS Device Farm - permissions for Android Instrumented test

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, aws-device-farm

Is it possible to grant secured permission for espresso instumented test in AWS device farm? I need to grant "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION", in Android 10 and above it's secured and can be granted only in the system settings for the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grant secured permission for espresso instumented test within custom YML File using below sample commands in pre_test phase

```
# These next lines set the permissions of the app
- adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- adb shell pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
- adb shell am start -W -n io.appium.settings/.Settings -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000
- adb shell appops set io.appium.settings android:mock_location allow
```